# Display all entries matching field of a section

Tags: loop, set, relatedto

I have two sections:
Games
Publishers

Games has a field called 'GamesPublisher' that is Entries type (set to Publishers)

I have a publisher called 'Microsoft' with an ID of 49.

I want to display all Game entries for the Publisher 'Microsoft' (ie ID 49)

I also want to set the order of the displaying in ASC order based on the field 'GamesCatalogNumber' which is in the section Games.

So far, it looks OK, but I have yet to figure out to limit entries to a specific Publisher.
http://www.colorcomputergames.com/tandy-catalog/

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('games').relatedTo(entry) %}
    <ul>
    {% for entry in entries.order('GamesCatalogNumber desc') %}
     <li>{{ entry.GamesCatalogNumber }}: <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {# Set parameters for prev/next elements list #}
    {% set params = craft.entries.section('publishers').order('title asc') %}

    {# Get the prev/next elements #}
    {% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
    {% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}

    {# And make sure to only output the links if the element exists #}
    {% if prevEntry %}<a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">Previous Publisher</a>{% endif %}
    {% if nextEntry %}<a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">Next Publisher</a>{% endif %}
```

Comment: I have the above somewhat working, but I don't think my solution is efficient. As only the publisher 'Microsoft' (ID:49) will every have data in the field GamesCatalogNumber, I put an IF statement to only display the <li> if that field is not empty.
Oddly, it works when the FOR loop is set to order in DESC order but fails in ASC order.
http://www.colorcomputergames.com/tandy-catalog/test.html

Comment: What field type is `GamesCatalogNumber `?

Comment: @AndréElvan, GamesCatalogNumber is just a TEXT field.

Comment: Regarding the problem with the sorting, if the field is text, it will be sorted as a text string, even if the value is a number, so this will not make any sense. Try changing it to a Number field.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your solution is mostly correct, except for handling the `gamesCatalogNumber`. For that you could either:

- test for specific publisher(s) by id or slug
- test if gamesCatalogNumber is empty on the first entry (and assume that the publisher doesn't use catalog numbers), or
- (recommended solution) add a `checkbox` or `lightSwitch` field to the publisher called 'usesCatalogNumbers' and test for that.

Something like:

```
{# publisher template #}

{% if entry.usesCatalogNumbers %}
    {% set games = craft.entries.section('games').relatedTo(entry).order('gamesCatalogNumber desc') %}
{% else %}
    {% set games = craft.entries.section('games').relatedTo(entry).order('title asc') %}
{% endif %}

<ul>
    {% for game in games %}
        <li>{% if entry.usesCatalogNumbers %}{{ entry.gamesCatalogNumber }}: {% endif %}<a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% set params = craft.entries.section('publishers').order('title asc') %}
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}
{% if prevEntry %}<a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">Previous Publisher</a> {% endif %}{% if nextEntry %}<a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">Next Publisher</a>{% endif %}
```

I recommend this (instead of the other options) because it's a bit more explicit and extensible (i.e. allows you to add other publishers that use catalog numbers without modifying the templates).

Comment: Revisiting this... Setting aside the Publisher section aspect of the original post. I think I just want to list out all games that contains 'something' (not null) in the field GamesCatalogNumber. Running into problems also getting it to work with pagination. :-(